# Escaping @ in Blazor

Tags: escaping, blazor

I want to display image from icon library in Blazor component.

The path is:

*wwwroot/lib/@icon/open-iconic/icons/account-login.svg*

But **@** is a special character in Blazor.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Quoting [Razor syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.0#razor-syntax):

> To escape an @ symbol in Razor markup, use a second @ symbol:
>
> `<p>@@Username</p>`
>
> The code is rendered in HTML with a single @ symbol:
>
> `<p>@Username</p>`

Comment: That is useful link to keep at hand, there are some other gotchas (generics, rules for email addresses).

Answer (score 16):

Just add another @ symbol. So your exmaple:

```
wwwroot/lib/@@icon/open-iconic/icons/account-login.svg
```

will render as:

> wwwroot/lib/@icon/open-iconic/icons/account-login.svg