# I can't create a tiktok page link because there's an @ but the other links work fine. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: html, hyperlink, blazor, tiktok

I'm building a website in HTML (mostly). It is a blazor application on visual studios. This is the code. The first two buttons work but there is an error around the @ in the TikTok one. Does anyone know what to do? The table is so I can have the button side by side. It is a TikTok PAGE, not a VIDEO. everyone else keeps telling me to embed a video. It's supposed to take them to TikTok so they can follow.

```
<table class="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button Class=accordion-item onclick="window.location.href='https://www.instagram.com/ringle.ye/'">
                <img src="Images/Contact us/instagram (1).png" width=250/>
                <h2>Instagram</h2>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button Class=accordion-item onclick='window.location.href="https://www./tiktok.com/@ringle.ye/"'>
                <img src="Images/Contact us/372102690_TIKTOK_LOGO_1080.png" width=250/> 
                <h2>TikTok</h2>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button Class=accordion-item onclick="window.location.href='mailto:RingleRings@gmail.com'">
                <img src="Images/Contact us/apple-mail.png" width=250/>
                <h2>Mail</h2>
            </button>
        </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

The link requires an @ for it to go to the right place (otherwise error 404). I've tried other things but they're messy and don't work.

Comment: You need to use @@ to escape the symbol.  See this SO question for the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59053960/escaping-in-blazor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Escaping @ in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59053960/escaping-in-blazor)

Comment: don't use magic strings - put those strings into variables (or do the @@ thing if you want your code to stare at you). Also, use `<a>` elements for links that navigate - buttons are for local actions.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
href="@("https://www./tiktok.com/@ringle.ye/")"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

may be you can try this

```
<a href="@("https://www.tiktok.com/@ringle.ye")"><h2>TikTok</h2></a>
```

hope can help you